# Change width and height of an image with aspect ratio

Tags: php, image, resize

I have this code, for changing the width of the image:

```
function resize_img($file,$width,$height=null){
    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($ext=='jpg' || $ext=='jpeg'){
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    } else if($ext=='png'){
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($file);
    }

    $img_w = imagesx($img);
    $img_h = imagesy($img);

    $ratio = $width / $img_w;
    $new_h = $img_h * $ratio;
    $new_h = $height??$new_h;

    $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$new_h);
    imagecopyresampled($new_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $new_h, $img_w, $img_h);
    if($ext=='jpg' || $ext=='jpeg'){
        imagejpeg($new_img, $file, 82);
    } else if($ext=='png'){
        imagepng($new_img, $file);
    }
}
```

I would like to add the ability to change the width along with the height while keeping the aspect. Now resolution is changing, but isn't filled (it's streched) How can I do that? Is this possible?

Comment: That it will fill that space. Similar to how the object-fit feature works in css

Comment: Take a look at this class: https://github.com/jspit-de/Gdimage

Comment: It is not possible to do this in pure php? For example something with this function `imagecopyresampled`?

Comment: Gdimage.php is only 1 file with no further dependencies. If you don't want to use the class you can see how the adjust method solves the problem there.